# Nested for with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to build a registration form where when the user signs up, i also create a store for him. For the registration i'm using devise.
routes.rb

```
devise_for :owners
```

owner.rb

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
                  :stores_attributes

  has_many :stores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stores
```

store.rb

```
  attr_accessible :city, :country, :locale, :name, :time_zone
  belongs_to :owner
```

I want to create as well as store for this user using a nester form, the form works well for the owner part, but not the nested fields.

I've been looking through similar questions, but for some reason it still doesn't work.

views/devise/registrations/new

### Sign up

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

    <%= f.fields_for :stores do |store_form| %>
      <p><%= store_form.label :name %></p>
      <p><%= store_form.text_field :name %></p>
    <% end %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't show the stores part of the form, does anyone have any ideas of what is wrong with my code?
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a =

```
<%= f.fields_for :stores do |store_form| %>
```